# Animating object on the stage using ActionScript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation

I mean only ActionScript. Is that possible to animate an object so that it moves on pre-drawn in Flash Professional trajectory? I know, I can use onEnterFrame with some math equations to move object around, but what if trajectory is too complicated? You see, I don't even know how to formulate the question. Hope you got me right. Thank you for any hints or tips in advance :))

Comment: So you want to animated something along a path, where the path is a line drawn in the Flash IDE? Why do you need ActionScript for this?

Comment: Because I want to do this repeatedly for random objects, so that neither order nor the actual moving object is known at compilation time... Also, I may want to remove some objects while they're moving on their paths and that also will be arranged on run-time :SS So, is that possible? :SS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your motion Tween visually. Right-click on the tween in the Timeline. Select 'Copy Motion as ActionScript 3.0'.

After that, you can just build a function using that code and pass your object to the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

In Flash Professional, attach and tween an empty sprite or a sprite with a dummy inside which you can hide/remove (if you want to have a visual reference in the IDE), along your path, just like you would with a "static" animation. The trick lies in the fact that with ActionScript you will be able to reference the parent sprite at runtime and add a child of your choosing to it, at the origin. Don't forget to remove or hide the dummy if you choose to use one.

That way, you will have the impression of your added child sprite animating along the path. Per your requirement, your code can be made to choose the order and what to move, at runtime.

It's either that, or like others have suggested, you define your path with points by means of ActionScript, and tween an object of your choosing along the imagined interpolated path, with code again. There's no shortage of tweening libraries out there.

I am pretty sure the first option requires less code and is less taxing on the player as far as resulting animation is concerned. It's what people did back in the old days of Flash :-) But many Flash Player application developers these days often wish to do as much as possible with code, reasons several.

Comment: So far this is the most pragmatic approach that requires minimum code!

Answer (score 2):

However complicated a trajectory is, it will always come down to a succession of points. Get these points in an Array/Vector and you should be able to manipulate any display object along that path. So yes, it should be possible.

In order to move your object, you can use the Timer class or some tweening, not only enter frame.

Comment: As always I recommend Greensock's Tweening classes for this kind of thing. In this instance [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenMax.html) and the bezier array.

Comment: Thank you, but HOW am I going to transform path into an array? o.O

Comment: @PatrickS Moving along a curved trajectory is way more difficult than you present it to be - just a succession of points. What points? How dense are these points - evenly distributed or getting denser around the curliest parts of a trajectory? Does the object going to move with a constant speed along all of the points? It's not that easy!

Comment: @Vladimir It's not the moving part that's difficult, it's the creation of the series of points. What you're talking about is the resolution of the series of points, how fine grain one needs it to be...

Comment: @PatrickS Exactly! Even when you calculate the series for a simple Bezier curve most likely the function would give you more points closer to the ends of the curve and less points in the middle. When you move an object along such points it would appear that is start slowly, accelerates at the curve and then slows down near the end point. It's just math. The problem of getting evenly distributed points along a curve is not that trivial.

Comment: @Vladimir It's a basic answer to a basic question. I don't really see where we disagree, nowhere in my answer did I imply it was easy, it all depends on the type of complexity the op is looking for.

Comment: @PatrickS I don't see a disagreement too. The intent of my comments is to further clarify the subject and to present all facts - this is not an interpersonal disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define the path you want the objects to take using a path that is computed using ActionScript (at least this will make it easier to move the object along that path).

When you draw a path in the Flash Auth. Tool, you are not storing the actual path, but just the graphics of the path (at runtime), so you have no points data available to tell your object where to go.

If you create a `Vector` of `Point`s, where the points are x, y co-ordinates on the stage, you can then `Tween` between each of the points in the `Vector`.

You will have the points stored in the `Vector` and they can be applied to any `Sprite` or `MovieClip` randomly. The `Tween` class can 'fill the gaps' between points in a `Vector`.

An interesting aside: you can make much smoother paths automatically between points (in the Vector) using a Catmull-Rom curved spline. Here is a class library that contains that functionality: http://www.algorithmist.net/as3pc.html

People use these splines to load the paths that 3D viewport cameras follow to get a smooth view as the camera moves around a scene.

Comment: Okay, but HOW am I going to create `Vector` of `Points`? o.O

Answer (score 1):

To get values for the points (for use as proposed by the other answers here), you could try using Mario Klingemann's shape decoder, preferably on a swf that contains only the path:

http://www.quasimondo.com/shapedecoder/qm_shape_decoder.php